Trigger PWA installation prompt a second time on Android phones
If I visit a PWA website (e.g. BMW.com), my Android phone shows an installation dialog (as it should). If I install the PWA, uninstall it later and visit the website again, the dialog is not shown anymore. I deleted already the browser data, but still the dialog is not shown when visiting the site again. I assume, my Android system or the browser stores the list of previously installed PWAs (or at least visited PWA sites). Is there a way to see and delete this information? This would be really helpful for testing-purposes.
